# How to rewrite domain with Yii urlManager

Tags: php, apache, yii, dns, social-networking

I've installed [humhub](https://github.com/humhub/humhub) to one of my servers. There's a reverse proxy server at the entrance of my network and the humhub server works behind it. A domain name is given to the humhub server:'vm-humhub'.

I want to rewrite URLs because humhub puts all URLs with the domain name 'vm-humhub', which is not valid when accessing out of my network. I want to replace `http://vm-humhub` into `https://mydomain.com`.

I first tried to rewrite URLs by apache, writing in default-ssl.conf like this:

```
<Location /humhub>
    ProxyPass http://vm-humhub/humhub
    ProxyPassReverse http://vm-humhub/humhub
    RequestHeader set X_Forwarded_proto 'https'
    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://vm-humhub/humhub/ https://mydomain.com/humhub/
    ProxyHTMLExtended On
    ProxyHTMLCharsetOut utf8
</Location>
```

When I see the HTML, all the URLs were successfully rewrited. However, javascript didn't work well and the page stops loading messages.

Because humhub works on Yii framework, I thought it natural rewriting urls using urlManager of Yii (And official install guide writs so).

However, I know nothing of Yii. After googling a while, I wrote in the conf file:

```
<?php return array (
  'components' =>
  array (
    'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'get',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
      'http://vm-humhub' => 'https://mydomain.com',
    ),
),
....
```

But nothing happened. Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can rewrite the domain in the same way as you can rewrite the URLs since the domain was used to locate your Yii code.

Answer (score 0):

I thing the base problem is that you have an error in your proxy pass configuration.

I've basically the same setup working using these parameters in apache config:

```
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Hope that helps - maybe someone else who stumbbles on this post as it's quite old ;-)